# t2.micro instance not showing in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to change from t1.micro to t2.micro in Elastic Beanstalk.

I followed the exact same steps, including checking the VPC option in the [following steps](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx2597LDLF7DPRW/Using-New-T2-Instances-With-an-Existing-Elastic-Beanstalk-App).

My problem is that in the next step I only see the t1.micro instance option, not the t2.micro instance.

How can I enable t2.micro in Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T2 instances use Hardware Virtualization (HVM) in order to get the best possible performance from the underlying CPU and require an HVM AMI. As a result, if you try to migrate an existing Elastic Beanstalk environment (that is based on a paravirtualized AMI) to T2, you will notice that the new instances do not appear in the list.

Check the virtualization type of your instance in EC2 - it must be 'hvm' to be able to become a T2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Faced a slightly but not exactly similar situation.

I had an Elastic Beanstalk environment running for the last few days. I assumed it's utilizing free-tier resources. But one day, suddenly after seeing my bill amount, I realized it was running `t4.large` ec2 instance. Even when I tried changing instance type from Capacity settings, I didn't get the option to change instance type to `t2.micro`. Then after some research I could figure out what the issue was:

Unkowingly, my EBS environment was using `arm64` processor, and `t2.micro` isn't supported by `arm64` processor architecture. As per the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html), we can't change the environment architecture after the environment is created. I had to create another fresh environment again making sure I am choosing `x86` architecture this time. Even though `x86` is still the default architecture while creating a new environment, EBS seems to be suggesting choosing `arm64` as the suggested processor architecture. That is probably why I landed up in that mess.

Answer (score 0):

Which solution stack are you using? In case you are using the Python solution stack, can you double check you are using v1.0.4 version- "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Python 2.7". This version of the solution stack comes with t2 support.